# Can someone explain why this java class won't compile?

Tags: java

I'm a java newb and I was trying to compile this but it won't compile.  Can someone help?  It says that void is an illegal start of an expression.  I got this from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html.  When I delete the main method and its closing bracket it compiles.  Why is this?  How can i write this with the main method included in the class?

```
class Bicycle{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

   void changeCadence(int newValue){
       cadence = newValue;
   }

    void changeGear(int newValue){
        gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment){
        speed = speed + increment;
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement){
        speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates(){
        System.out.println("cadence: " + cadence + " speed: " +speed + " gear: " + gear);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Side note: this way of learning syntax and stuff is not very efficient. Do you intend to come up with a new question every time the compilers barks at you? Better way of doing it: keep things small: just write down a few lines of code (of which you think should be correct). Then run the compiler. Read the error messages very carefully. Fix. Repeat. And maybe, study about the "structural" properties of Java first; like in here; which elements go where in a class?!

Answer (score 2):

You put the `main` method in the wrong place. The `main` method shouldn't contain the methods and members of the class.

You should extract the main method :

```
class Bicycle{

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue){
       cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue){
        gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment){
        speed = speed + increment;
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement){
        speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates(){
        System.out.println("cadence: " + cadence + " speed: " +speed + " gear: " + gear);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // here you can create an instance of the class and test it
        Bicycle bike = new Bicycle ();
        bike.changeCadence(4);
        bike.changeGear(5);
        bike.speedUp(3);
        bike.printStates();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized my main method shouldn't have been jammed in when I was laying out the methods of the class (right?).

Answer (score 0):

Just a thumb rule-

A method block in java class can't have another method block inside it. Yes we can create a local inner class inside a method block and then it can consist methods but not directly.

Comment: Oh okay so main is a method so it can't define the changeGear and applyBreaks and those other methods within it? Thanks!  How do you, out of curiosity, make a local inner class?  That sounds like it might be too advanced for me for now.

Comment: Why do the methods have "void" in front of them?

Comment: void means, this  method won't return any kind of value (primitive or class object). To read more about local class, please visit [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).